# opening an already existing txt file on button click in c# windows form

Tags: c#

My requirement is that when i click a button (C# windows form) of my application,an already existing txt file should get opened in notepad.

I have already tried the above code :

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        String str = txt1.Text;
        ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Users\\gaurav_joshi\\My Documents\\test.txt");
        ps.UseShellExecute = false;
        ps.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        p.StartInfo = ps;
        p.Start();

        p.StandardInput.Write("This is a test.");
        p.StandardInput.Flush();
        p.StandardInput.Close();
    }
```

But when i run the program an exception is occuring as follows
Win32 Exception 
"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"

With streamReader i can read the file but i want to launch the notepad or wordpad itself to read that particular existing file.

Can somebody help me with the above problem

Answer (score 6):

Simply you can try this:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", "C:\\Users\\gaurav_joshi\\My Documents\\test.txt")
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is use this code:

```
    Process.Start("C:\\Users\\gaurav_joshi\\My Documents\\test.txt");
```

You might need this if you don't have it already:

```
    Using System.Diagnostics;
```

This will open the text file in your default text editor, to open it in notepad, use this:

```
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", "C:\\Users\\gaurav_joshi\\My Documents\\test.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute *notepad.exe* and pass the file it is to open as a command line argument to it.

If you're trying to invoke behaviour regarding file associations (i.e. attempting to invoke a *.txt* file automatically opens it in *notepad.exe*), then `UseShellExecute=false` [is not what you want (note link).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx)

Comment: The last part of your answer is the important/correct part. Don't hard-code a path to Notepad, just let the shell handle it. Set `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

Comment: Why would you hard code a path to _notepad.exe_ when it's in the PATH?  He specifically talks about "_notepad_", so he may be interested in safeguarding against people changing the default behaviour of _.txt_ files (I believe installing [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) gives the option to do this, among other possibilities).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
ps.FileName = "NotePad.exe";
ps.Arguments = "C:\\Users\\gaurav_joshi\\My Documents\\test.txt";
p.StartInfo = ps;
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String file_name="c:\\log.txt";
Process.start("notepad",file_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\gaurav_joshi\\My Documents\\test.txt");
```